# NetSuite update Assembly Build with csv

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

we are trying to implement a system where we export the details of a work order (as csv) and import it into our manufacturing system for production. That part is working well, however the manufacturing system returns a csv with additional details we would like stored in NetSuite.

I have created all the fields and applied them to the AssemblyBuild but then I realized there is not CSV update for Assembly Builds. I was hoping someone here might have a solution for how to update the Assembly Build.

My thoughts so far are creating a custom record type with the custom fields and somehow linking that to the build since I can csv upload/update for custom record types.

I'm also open to scripting a solution but wasn't sure how to do it within NetSuite. I'm almost tempted to create a hosted webapp where you type in the Assembly Build ID, upload a CSV there for parsing and the application connects using suitetalk to update the record.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My thoughts so far are creating a custom record type with the custom fields and somehow linking that to the build since I can csv upload/update for custom record types.

This would work.  To link it to the Build you would just need to have a field in the custom record containing the build id, then create a User Event script set to fire on `afterSubmit` when the custom record is created.  Within the UE script you can load the build, then set the relevant fields from the custom record.  The custom record will be available within the UE script as `currentRecord`.

During the CSV import, you will need to make sure the 'Run server SuiteScript and trigger workflows' option is selected under Advanced Options on the Import Options page.

For better import performance you could set it up as a Scheduled Script or Map Reduce Script instead of a User Event and run the workload in batches.  This requires a slightly different approach whereby you need to search for and load the relevant custom records, then load the builds and so on.

Revert back with more specific questions with further details if you run into trouble - good luck!

Comment: very cool, I wasn't even thinking of the script part to update the assembly with this option. Thank you!